# Self-signed SSL connection using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo, x509

I'm trying to create a secure SSL connection to MongoDB using PyMongo. The goal is to use this configuration for a Mongo instance running on EC2 to which I can connect with a Python client. For testing, I'm just trying to get the configuration working locally first. My as yet failing attempt can be found [here](https://github.com/aisthesis/mongo-ssl).

Short version of what I think is the problem: My client side certificate authority file `ca.pem` isn't correct. The way I have it, this file is actually identical to the one I'm using server side. Both were created using `x509` with `openssl`, and I suspect that my client side file needs some kind of different content, but I'm not sure exactly how to generate that content or if this suspicion is even correct.

Here are the details of what I've done for creating the necessary certificates and keys (on Mac El Capitan):

First, generate a certificate authority:

```
$ mkdir ~/ssl
$ cd ~/ssl
$ openssl req -out ca.pem -new -x509 -days 3650    
# enter info
```

Generate server `.pem` file:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
$ openssl req -key server.key -new -out server.req
# enter info
$ openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out server.crt -days 3650
$ cat server.key server.crt > server.pem
```

Now do the same for the client:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
$ openssl req -key client.key -new -out client.req
$ openssl x509 -req -in client.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out client.crt -days 3650
$ cat client.key client.crt > client.pem
```

Then I do the following configurations in `etc/mongod.conf`:

```
net:
  ...
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: ~/ssl/server.pem
    CAFile: ~/ssl/ca.pem
```

Now starting mongo (Mac) with

```
$ mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

works as expected. The process runs and seems to be accepting the configurations.

Then on the Python side (also running on localhost for debugging), I do the following in calling mongo:

```
import ssl
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(
        '127.0.0.1',
        27017,
        ssl=True,
        ssl_certfile='~/ssl/client.pem',
        ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
        ssl_ca_certs='~/ssl/ca.pem'
        )
# try a simple insert
```

When I run this, the Python code blocks after creating the `MongoClient`, and I see in the `mongo` logs:

```
2016-03-03T22:11:30.331-0800 E NETWORK  [conn21] SSL: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

On the basis of Wan's comment below, I redid the whole thing, making sure that the information in the 'Distinguished Name' was consistent with those specifications. The old version definitely used the same Common Name for both server and client. The connection still isn't succeeding, but the messages are somewhat different:

```
2016-03-11T12:29:40.380-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57363 #3 (1 connection now open)
2016-03-11T12:29:40.386-0800 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:57363 (0 connections now open)
```

These 2 messages just repeat until I stop the Python process, which blocks when attempting to open the connection. The `end connection` part is now in the place where the `alert unknown ca` line was previously in the mongo log.

Additional info for debugging:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem client.pem
client.pem: OK
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server.pem
server.pem: OK
$ openssl x509 -noout -subject -in server.pem
subject= /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=codeMelon/OU=Engineering/CN=server.com/emailAddress=<my-email-address>@gmail.com
$ openssl x509 -noout -subject -in client.pem
subject= /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=codeMelon/OU=Engineering/CN=client.com/emailAddress=<my-email-address>@gmail.com
```

The bottom line after getting the subject line properly formed is that mongo is accepting the connection, then ending it, and the Python process is blocking without ever making the intended insert.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This operation should be a fairly common way to secure a publicly accessible MongoDB. Surely someone on here has done it if I can only get their attention :) I'm happy to start over from scratch rather than debug what I have, if anyone can provide instructions that will work.

Comment: If I replicate your steps (even creating the `file.srl` by following your links), it works. Few things to check: 1) Run `openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem client.pem` to verify the client and server pem against the CA. 2) Make sure the `subj` or info that you entered in has a matching information i.e. /C=<Country Name>/ST=<State>/L=<Locality Name>/O=<Organisation Name>/emailAddress=<email> , but have different value for CN=<Common Name> CA/server/client. If you still have question post your an example of your `subj` value.

Comment: Redoing it so that server and client side agree on everything except CN eliminated the `alert unknown ca` coming from the mongo side. But the mongo just accepts, then ends the connection, and the Python process still blocks. I edited the original post to give the outputs you wanted to look at.

Comment: Re-running with your fixes, it now looks to me more like my client doesn't have write permissions to the database. In my toy client test code, I added a `print` statement that shows everything going as expected until the client actually tries to *write* to the db.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) run `hostname` in your server (assuming your are on *nix system). Add an _extra_ `CN` to your `subj` for the server with the hostname. Change your MongoClient `127.0.0.1` value to match the hostname (which also you have a quote instead of a dot before the 1), or see [sslAllowInvalidHostnames](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--sslAllowInvalidHostnames) flag. 2) Try to connect using `mongo` shell instead of your python script to get the SSL sorted first before adding an extra script. Let me know how you go.

Comment: the quote was a mistake in entering the data here. Investigating your other suggestions.

Comment: Can I use an IP address as CN? I think the easiest way to debug might be running Mongo on a VM. The obvious didn't work with both on localhost. So I'll set up a Virtual Box tomorrow.

Comment: Although not recommended to use IP as CN, you can. see [RFC-6125](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-1.7.2). If it's for the SSL test, you don't need a separate VM. Try the `mongod` `sslAllowInvalidHostnames` flag, if you just want to ignore the hostname issue for now, and connect using `mongo` shell.

Comment: Passing `sslAllowInvalidHostnames` to the mongo shell on localhost allowed the connection. Now figuring out how to map that to PyMongo options.

Comment: Got it working with PyMongo on localhost by passing the parameter `ssl_match_hostname=False` to `MongoClient()`. If you want to summarize the results as answer, I'll be happy to give you a "correct answer". Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are other ways of generating server/client pem with a [Certificate Authority](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#certificate-authorities) i.e. without involving `file.srl`, but this answer is to follow up on the question.

Worth mentioning that most MongoDB v3.0+ distributions now include support for SSL, please be sure to choose a package that supports SSL. The example below is tested with [MongoDB v3.2](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production) on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 with [PyMongo v3.2.1](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/). Where a single machine generated the CA, server and client pem files for demonstration purposes.

Let's generate `ca.pem` and `privkey.pem`. The subject structure is `/C=<Country Name>/ST=<State>/L=<Locality Name>/O=<Organisation Name>/emailAddress=<email>/CN=<Common Name>`.

```sh
mkdir ~/ssl
cd ~/ssl
openssl req -out ca.pem -new -x509 -days 3650 -subj "/C=AU/ST=NSW/O=Organisation/CN=root/emailAddress=user@domain.com"
```

Generate `server .pem` file:

```sh
hostname  # note down the value
echo "00" > file.srl # two random digits number
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -key server.key -new -out server.req -subj  "/C=AU/ST=NSW/O=Organisation/CN=server1/CN=<hostname value>/emailAddress=user@domain.com"
openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out server.crt -days 3650
cat server.key server.crt > server.pem
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server.pem
```

Although you can use IP address as `CN` value as well, it is not recommended. See [RFC-6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-1.7.2).

Now let's generate `client.pem` file:

```sh
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -key client.key -new -out client.req -subj "/C=AU/ST=NSW/O=Organisation/CN=client1/emailAddress=user@domain.com"
openssl x509 -req -in client.req -CA ca.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out client.crt -days 3650
cat client.key client.crt > client.pem
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem client.pem
```

After generating the `.pem` files, now you can run [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#mongod). for example:

```sh
mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile ~/server.pem --sslCAFile ~/ca.pem
```

You can test the connection using the [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo), for example:

```sh
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile ~/client.pem --sslCAFile ~/ca.pem --host <server hostname>
```

Once you can get connected successfully, you can try with PyMongo. For example:

```py
import ssl 
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(
    '<server hostname>',
    27017,
    ssl=True,
    ssl_certfile='~/client.pem',
    ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
    ssl_ca_certs='~/ca.pem'
 )
```

Alternatively, you can also use `mongod` flag [--sslAllowInvalidHostnames](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--sslAllowInvalidHostnames) to specify `localhost`, etc.

For production use, your MongoDB deployment should use valid certificates generated and signed by a single certificate authority. If you use a self-signed certificate, although the communications channel will be encrypted, there will be no validation of server identity. Using a certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority will permit MongoDB drivers to verify the server’s identity. In general, avoid using self-signed certificates unless the network is trusted.

Other related links that you may find useful:

- [MongoDB: Configure SSL](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/).
- [MongoDB: Security Tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/).
- [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/).

Comment: The server and the client **MUST** have different O or OU field otherwise, the certificate is seen as another server in the cluster, and not a user. Just add the OU field to differentiate if needed.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, the first step I had to do to get this to work was `cd ~/; openssl rand -writerand .rnd` to esnure the .rnd file existed in the expected path, otherwise I couldn't continue.

Comment: This is the best example I have found to help me learn how to do this.  What would it look like if there was also an intermediate CA?